# animationEnd/.removeClass not functioning in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I am trying to remove a class at the end of an animation in Javascript, and it works fine in Chrome but it doesn't work in Firefox.

What is supposed to happen is on mouseenter, a class (.shine) is added to another class (greentile). .shine plays a sprite animation in CSS then Javascript removes it from greentile. Except in Firefox .shine stays, meaning the animation only plays once and never again.

```
$(".greentile").bind("webkitAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd", function () 
{
    $(this).removeClass("shine");
});

$(".greentile").mouseenter(function () 
{
    $(this).addClass("shine");
});
```

This is so simple that I feel like it shouldn't be a problem, and it's very frustrating. The Firefox Inspector shows that the mouseenter is still being fired, which leads me to believe that it simply isn't removing .shine. I have also tried changing and detecting prefixes on AnimationEnd for compatibility, I've looked at dozens of related or semi-related issues on here and elsewhere (like Github, Doctype, CSS Tricks) and I've perused w3schools, javascript documentation and Firefox documentation and I still can't figure this out.

I'm very new to web development so please forgive me if I've overlooked something obvious.
Thanks

**Edit:** here is a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SteveyN/4N6Cw/6/) showing it in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the event is case-sensitive. Firefox listens to the official name [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) (note the lower-case `E`!) and not the older `mozAnimationEnd` anymore.

Comment: Oh my god I knew it was going to be something simple. It works now, thank you very much!